# How do we notify the Foundation of a phishing scam so they can warn Blender users?

Tags: modeling, rendering, sculpting

Member Huda of the facebook "Blender" groups found an ad that hijacks you over to "https://www.biender.site/", where you see a clone of the 3.83.3 LTS splash screen... and then the links funnel you over to their supposed Blender 2.83 download page where you can download a 1.3MB trojan for god knows what.

If you don't pay attention to the address bar, everything in there looks legit.

Can the Foundation please be informed so they can decide what action they want to take?

Screenshot of ad taken by group member:

[image: BadBlenderLink]

Comment: so maybe contact them at foundation (at) blender (dot) org

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about using Blender.

Comment: I would use the contact details [here](https://www.blender.org/foundation/) or [here](https://www.blender.org/institute/).

Comment: Better to notify ads provider.

Comment: Ton Roosendaal just tweeted about this. Thanks for reporting it :). https://twitter.com/tonroosendaal/status/1289920735465496577